# jquery get value of table cells in column, add values together and output on page

Tags: jquery, addition

This may seem a bit of bizarre question, and I'm not sure if it's possible.

I have created a HTML table in wordpress, and have built a PHP loop to output post data in table format.

I am using this [jQuery table sorted plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to make it a sortable table.

But my question is, is it possible using jQuery to add up all the numerical values in my table `<th>Hours</th>` column and output the result?

If a class needs to added to the `<td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Labour Time Hours', true); ?></td>` cell then that's cool, it will not affect the tablesorter.

Then I would like to output the result in my table footer cell.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find anything on google but I'm probably search for the wrong term.

Thanks

**MY WORDPRESS LOOP GENERATING TABLE CONTENT**

```
<?php 

        $data = new WP_Query(array(

        'post_type'         => 'job',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'orderby'           => 'date'

)); ?>

<?php if ($data->have_posts()) : ?>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 

    <thead> 

        <tr> 

            <th>Date</th> 
            <th>Job Title</th> 
            <th>Category</th> 
            <th>Hours</th> 

        </tr> 

    </thead> 

    <tbody> 

        <?php while ($data->have_posts()) : $data->the_post(); ?>

        <tr> 

            <td><?php the_time('Y/m/d'); ?></td> 
            <td><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="View Job" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></td> 
            <td><?php the_category(', ') ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Labour Time Hours', true); ?></td> 

        </tr> 

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </tbody>

    <tfoot>

        <tr>

            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><!-- Total to go here --></td>

        </tr>

    </tfoot>

</table>

<?php unset($data); endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this would be to assign a class to the elements that you want to add up.

So you would do something like this:

```
<td class="add">5</td>
<td class="add">8</td>
<td id="Total"></td>
```

Then, if you're absolutely positive that these values will always be ints (or floats), you can do this

```
function adding() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".add").each(function(index, element) {
        total += parseInt($(element).text());
    });
    $("#Total").text(total);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seem very straight forward method, and I can see what the script does - but strangly nothing is outputted? I will make a fiddle and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some fairly simple jQuery:

```
var $table = $('#myTable'),
    $tr = $table.find('tbody tr'),
    totalHours = 0;

$tr.each(function(i, el){
    totalHours += parseInt($(this).find('td:last').html() || 0, 10);
});

$table.find('tfoot td:last').html(totalHours);
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/agVgU/)

Comment: This seems great, should be a straight copy and past of this and it will work on my loop. How ever, I just get `NaN` as a result. I will create a fiddle replicating my table and back to you. Thanks

Comment: One possible reason for the NaN could be that one of the values that you're parsing is an empty string. You could handle that by `var hours = parseInt($(this).find('td:last').html(), 10);
    totalHours += isNaN(hours) ? 0 : hours;`

Comment: Updated with fix for that use case.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to add on the server imo, but you can do this:

```
var total = 0;

 $("td.whateverClass").each(function () 
    { 
        total += $(this).text();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't really see whats happening here, is the var total my result, should I be able to use the total var to place this into my total cell?

Answer (score 0):

Add the class `hours` to your respective table cells `<td class='hours></td>'`

Then you can jQuery it like this.

`var sum = 0;`

then

`$('tbody td.hours').each(function(index, td)) { sum += parseInt(td.html()); });`

and finally

`$('tfoot td.hours').html(sum);`

Comment: Thanks, tho seem to get a parse error - says extra token but there is not. There appears to be an extra ) after ..index, td)) but if I remove that it still throws an error weirdly. I will get back to you with a fiddle